# Como delimitar uma campo string para uso na cláusula IN

Tags: sql-server

Na `tabela_A` possuo um campo `cod_canal` onde é um `INT`, na `tabela_B` possuo um campo `canais` do tipo string e que separa os códigos por `,`.
Exemplo: `1,3,6,9,12`.

Numa primeira tentativa, pensei apenas em fazer a cláusula da seguinte maneira:
`[...] WHERE tabela_A.cod_canal IN (tabela_B.canais) [...]`

E obviamente, recebi o erro:

> SQL Error [245] [S0001]: Conversion failed when converting the
>   nvarchar value '0,1,3,5,9,12' to data type int.
>   com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Conversion failed
>   when converting the nvarchar value '0,1,3,5,9,12' to data type int.

Tentei utilizar a função [`PATINDEX`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms188395.aspx), porém acredito não ter entendido o funcionamento correto dele e não tenho o resultado esperado

```
AND PATINDEX('%' + CAST(tabela_A.cod_canal AS NVARCHAR) + '%', tabela_B.canais) > 0
```

Como eu posso obter os resultados da `tabela_B` a partir do relacionamento entre os campos `cod_canal` e `canais`? Visto a diferença do tipo dos dados e formatos inseridos nos respectivos campos.

Comment: Você vai ter que converte para um array de inteiros

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você tem que converter sua string para uma list, para isso seria necessário uma FUNCTION para ser usada dentro do seu select.

```
create FUNCTION [dbo].[fnStringList2Table]
(
    @List varchar(MAX)
)
RETURNS 
@ParsedList table
(
    item int
)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @item varchar(800), @Pos int

    SET @List = LTRIM(RTRIM(@List))+ ','
    SET @Pos = CHARINDEX(',', @List, 1)

    WHILE @Pos > 0
    BEGIN
        SET @item = LTRIM(RTRIM(LEFT(@List, @Pos - 1)))
        IF @item <> ''
        BEGIN
            INSERT INTO @ParsedList (item) 
            VALUES (CAST(@item AS int))
        END
        SET @List = RIGHT(@List, LEN(@List) - @Pos)
        SET @Pos = CHARINDEX(',', @List, 1)
    END

    RETURN
END
```

E chama da seguinte forma.

```
SELECT      *
FROM   tabela_A.cod_canal IN (SELECT item from fnStringList2Table(@statuslist))
```